# Log4Net Dependency injection with origin

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

I want to inject log4net with dependency injections, but still pass the origin.

I can't pass the origin in the `LogManager.GetLogger(typeof("classname"))`, because the logger is already created in the service.

Is there any way to pass the parameter after the creation of `ILog`?
(I'm not using Unity, so no duplicate)

Comment: Possible Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846342/how-to-inject-log4net-ilog-implementations-using-unity-2-0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Inject Log4Net ILog implementations using Unity 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846342/how-to-inject-log4net-ilog-implementations-using-unity-2-0)

Comment: en is het al gelukt?

Comment: @Jan ja 2 maanden geleden al