# Spring - injecting Log4j logger without explicit specification

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, log4j

I'm using Spring XML-based DI to create my classes.

Also I'm using log4j and I'm injecting `org.apache.log4j.Logger` as a constructor argument in each class which needs it.

So I have a lot of entries in Spring config like following:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="com.myProject.MyClass">
    ...
    <constructor-arg type="org.apache.log4j.Logger">
        <bean class="org.apache.log4j.Logger" factory-method="getLogger">
            <constructor-arg value="com.myProject.MyClass"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Class code:

```
package com.myProject;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MyClass {
    private final Logger logger;

    public MyClass (
            ...
            Logger logger) {
        ...
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    ...
}
```

Although it works perfectly, I wonder if there is any possibility to default `constructor-arg` of the logger to the class name, whose constructor the created logger should be passed to?

E.g. like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35262698/2858407) for Unity DI and log4net which are somewhat analogs in .Net.

---

**Update:**

I see two reasons of injecting `Logger` rather than initializing it inside the class.

First of all, statements like `private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);` are usually copy-pasted, so they are prone to mistake in the logger name.

Moverover, I'd like to cover error logging with unit tests, e.g. pass a mock of `Logger` into the constructor and than verify that after some erroneous action `logger.Error` has been called.

Comment: why don't you use **private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);** ?

Comment: You can use project Lombok's annotation @Log to automatically inject logger if it's needed.
Here is an example: https://projectlombok.org/features/log

Comment: @DirkDeyne i'd like to inject a logger, e.g. to mock it in unit-tests and verify an error is logged.

Comment: there are better ways to test if logging happens.
[how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677/how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger)

Answer (score 1):

Passing the logger as a constructor parameter is somewhat terrible.
Also, your arguments against using a `private ...blah... Logger` are specious.

1. "copy-paste is error prone."
   True copy-paste techniques are error prone,
   but when you want each logger to have a unique name (so as to identify the source of the log message),
   you need to declare a logger in each class.
2. "I want to mock my loggers during unit tests."
   While it is not reasonable to replace a final member variable with a mock,
   it is ridiculously easy to to replace a not-final member variable with a mock.
   To this end,
   you should always declare class level loggers a follows: `private static Logger ...blah`.
   Specifically,
   don't use final loggers.
   Once the loggers are not final,
   use reflection to replace them with mocks.
3. [New in 2023; hurry for learnin'] Use protected loggers.
   Declare your logger as `static Logger ...blah` then assign it to a mockLogger in the `@BeforeEach` or `@BeforeAll` method in your Junit
   (jupiter) unit test.